# VBA userforms loading with every paste action

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am transferring data from user filled table to form created by group SAP team. Everytime I paste into the form, all the forms load in VBE, when the VBA code runs once or twice in loop, it is ok, but if there are more loops, the excel starts restarting or give me message out of memory and then restarts (both workbooks are pretty small in size, no large calculations...). Is there any way to stop this? Is it something my code induce?

The problem is seen [on this video](https://youtu.be/dneCpoTgHqY)

My code is just copy named range from userfilled form to namedrange (mostly) in SAP form.

most of the lines are consisted from variant of:

```
    wswbs.Range("rWBSID").Rows(cp).Copy
    wsaas.Range("bbu_psp").PasteSpecial
```

where cp is calculated row in range of cells

I am not eligible to remove the userforms, but some kind of deactivation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory and Excel restarting didn't occur after I switched of SAP Analysis add-in and started to run the code in with VBE closed. It is now much faster. Not sure if there is other solution